# Count files in folder that allow directory listing on web service

Tags: wget

There is a directory listing folder on web service look like this;

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/indices/

What is the best way to count a number of files or folders using a command line? (I tried to read manual about `wget` but I cannot do it.)

I do not want to download them, just count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
wget -qO - http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/indices/ | grep '^<tr><td' | wc -l
```

this number includes the 'Parent Directory' link, so you probably want to subtract one.